# Emacs cant get flymake working on emacs 24 (linux)

Tags: emacs

Good day, when load any source file into editor i get following message:

```
File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

and flymake simply not working then.
Starting with `--init-debug` does not improve anythong. Any idea how to debug the cause of problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This general error is thrown when a Lisp function actually expects a string argument but receives a `nil`.

Try setting `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the top of your *.emacs* to get a stack-trace showing you which string is `nil`. In case the error is caused by FlyMake settings in your *.emacs*: [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) is a good introduction.

The deeper reason for `wrong-type-argument` exceptions is that Lisp functions have no prototypes and cannot rely on the interpreter; they're always defined and hence need to parse their arguments on their own.

> The Emacs Lisp interpreter itself does not perform type checking on
>   the actual arguments passed to functions when they are called. [...]
>   It is therefore up to the individual function to test whether each 
>   actual argument belongs to a type that the function can use.

For more information see [Type Predicates](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_55.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual.